# Magento 2 - Override luma themes module less file

Tags: magento2, theme, overrides, css, less

I try to override css code from the file **vendor\magento\theme-frontend-luma\Magento_Checkout\web\css\source\module\_cart.less**:

```
.media-width(@extremum, @break) when (@extremum = 'min') and (@break = @screen__m) {
    .checkout-cart-index {
        .page-main {
            padding-left: @layout__width-xs-indent;
            padding-right: @layout__width-xs-indent;
        }
    }
...
```

So I created the file in my own theme and made my override

**MY_THEME\Magento_Checkout\web\css\source\module\_cart.less**.

```
.media-width(@extremum, @break) when (@extremum = 'min') and (@break = @screen__m) {
    .checkout-cart-index {
        .page-main {
            padding-left: 35px;
            padding-right: 35px;
        }
    }
}
```

Then I executed `grunt refresh` but the change is not getting applied.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer in the [documentation](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/frontend-dev-guide/css-guide/css_quick_guide_approach.html).

I had to create the file **MY_THEME\Magento_Checkout\web\css\source\_extend.less**

and make my override there.

Answer (score 0):

Did you configured the grunt for you custom theme? If not please refer the below link

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/frontend-dev-guide/tools/using_grunt.html

And you don't have configure grunt, You can run the setup upgrade and content deploy.

In my case it working well. Please check here  https://prnt.sc/12vd0q7